# issue send email via Sendgrid (Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sendgrid, newsletter

Since a couple of days i've got an Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe

When i try to send my newsletters with sendgrid email

My configuration is a ruby on rails(4.2)and heroku server

I dont understand because i send my newsletters with this configuration since 5 years and i Never had problèms ???

Now evry Times i have this type of issue :

Net::SMTPServerBusy: 450 Could not send e-mail

lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:532:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Notifier.send_mail_experience1(@mailgenerals,author,@offres,@destinataire,@grades).deliver
  lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:531:in`block in '
    @author.each do |author|
  config/initializers/sentry.rb:23:in `block in execute'
    orig_execute(args)
  config/initializers/sentry.rb:22:in`execute'
    Raven.capture logger: 'rake', tags: { 'rake_task' => @name } do
  bin/bundle:3:in `load'
    load Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle')

I try to configurate Sendgrid with anothor port but it is the same Way

Thank for your help

Julien

Comment: 450 – Your message was not delivered because the other user mailbox was not available. This can happen if the mailbox is locked or is not routable.

Comment: This is not your application issue  .  this is a MTA(mail transferring agent ie sentgrid) issue where your mail servers try to delivery messages to MX servers . I also had same problem but we have our own MTA I solved problem by changing the sending IP . Contact sentgrid support .